# Which hook to use to add notification message at beginning of my <body>

Tags: css, hooks, notifications

i want to add dynamic messages to the beginning of my  but I can't figure what hook to use. I have tried get_header but i can't append content to it... any idea? I don't want a solution that requires javasript as i want it to work without javascript.

Comment: and i want a solution that would work for any theme. It would be easy to just add a hook to the template but i want it to be universal and used on any theme.

Comment: And why do you want to add it at the beginning of body? I would add them at the end and use CSS to position it on top of the page. (Same method is used to show admin bar and it's much nicer for SEO)

Comment: would fit better at beginning of the body actually. It's error messages that are displayed when there are errors in a form submission for example. If it's not possible to add to the beginning of the body, then i guess the footer would be an alternative.

Comment: Well, nothing is impossible ;) But there is no hook at the begenning of body and there is at the end... So the second solution is easy to implement without any "hacking" at all.

Comment: yup i guess the footer is the way to go. I have looked in to the code and hooks and doesn't seem possible by default.

Comment: what hook can i use so that i appears after the wp-admin toolbar? i have used get_footer but it appears at beginning of footer